# Webpage Css Error.. Not Showing Anything

Tags: html, css

I am trying to write a basic layout out for calculator. How come when i try to run the web page, it's all empty !! Not sure which one is overriding the code. can some one help me out
This is my html code.

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="css/calculater.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="screen_one">
<div id="numberholder"></div>
<div id="numholder">
    <ul>
          <li class="num">1</li>
          <li class="num">2</li>
          <li class="num">3</li>
           <li class="num">4</li>
          <li class="num">5</li>
          <li class="num">6</li>
           <li class="num">7</li>
          <li class="num">8</li>
          <li class="num">9</li>
          <li class="num">0</li>
          <li class="num">+</li>
          <li class="num">-</li>
          <li class="num">=</li>
          <li class="num">/</li>
          <li class="num">*</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my css.

```
body,html{
height:100%;
width:100%;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
#numberholder{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width:100%;
height:10%;
}
#numholder{
position:absolute;
top:10%;
left:0;
height:90%;
font-size:0;
}
.class{
display:inline-block;
width:33.3%;
height:20%;
font-size:13px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Btw you don't have a body tag, and a font-size set to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the below css

```
#numholder {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

To

```
#numholder {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

or remove the below css code from your css

```
#numholder {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks!!that works. it was supposed to come out in rectangle shape.. like regular calculator layout and i am able to show it that way !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body,html{
height:100%;
width:100%;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
#numberholder{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width:100%;
height:10%;
}
#numholder{
position:absolute;
top:10%;
left:0;
height:90%;
font-size:1em;
}
.class{
display:inline-block;
width:33.3%;
height:20%;
font-size:13px;
text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="screen_one">
<div id="numberholder"></div>
<div id="numholder">
    <ul>
          <li class="num">1</li>
          <li class="num">2</li>
          <li class="num">3</li>
           <li class="num">4</li>
          <li class="num">5</li>
          <li class="num">6</li>
           <li class="num">7</li>
          <li class="num">8</li>
          <li class="num">9</li>
          <li class="num">0</li>
          <li class="num">+</li>
          <li class="num">-</li>
          <li class="num">=</li>
          <li class="num">/</li>
          <li class="num">*</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

------------------------------Output-------------------------------

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7
- 8
- 9
- 0
- +
- -
- =
- /
- *

Answer (score 0):

Remove `font-size:0;` in `#numholder` or change it to higher number:

Example - `font-size:1em;`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3y3fd/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you made the **font-size:0**

```
font-size:0;
```